# Error installing pyserial in Ubuntu

Tags: opencv, python

I was trying to install pyserial for linking ardunio with my opencv-python. When i was trying to install pyserial from the terminal,it was giving me errors..

OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyserial-3.3.dist-info'

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the user account being used have permission to write in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/`?

Comment: Yes, account have permission.